# Where is located flashlight activity on cm12

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.0-lollipop, camera-flash

As you know, on cm12 does not exist Torch.apk. Flashlight run on toggle in quick settings. I am wondering, which one application contain flashlight activity? I was Googling, but can't find an answer.